# Cannot invoke equals(boolean) on the primitive type boolean

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I want to check equality of first and last two characters of a string so i have written condition like

```
if (str.length() >= 4
            && ((str.startsWith(str.substring(0, 2))).equals(str.endsWith(str
                    .substring(str.length() - 3, str.length() - 1)))))
```

but I am getting error as
**Cannot invoke equals(boolean) on the primitive type boolean**

so what is the root cause?

Comment: There is a difference between primitive types (which aren't objects) and everything else.  `String#startsWith` returns a `boolean`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is coming because : str.startsWith() returns `boolean` value and we are calling `equals()` with **Boolean**

Use this expression to compare :

```
    str.substring(0, 2).equals(str.substring(str.length() - 3, str.length() - 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to check equality of first and last two characters of a string

That's not what you're doing though. You're using `startsWith` and `endsWith` - you're asking whether a string starts with its own first two characters, and whether it ends with some portion of the string near the end, and then trying to compare the results of those comparisons... except that you're trying to compare two `boolean` values with `equals` instead of `==`, which isn't going to work either.

You just want `substring` and `equals` here - but your `substring` is incorrect too, in that you have an off-by-one error for finding the last two characters. I would personally split this up for simplicity:

```
if (str.length() > 4) {
    String start = str.substring(0, 2);
    // If you don't specify an end point, it'll be "the rest of the string"
    // which is what you want.
    String end = str.substring(str.length() - 2);
    if (start.equals(end)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

endsWith api will return you a boolean value and hence compiler is compiling that you are trying to compare String with boolean. Instead you could do something like:

```
if (str.endsWith(str.substring(0, 2))) {
     //ye it does ends with same string as it starts with
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `startsWith(String)` returns a boolean indicating if the string it is being applied on effectively starts with the string argument. For comparing the first two characters with the last two ones, your boolean condition can be:

```
if(str.length() >= 4 && str.startsWith(str.substring(str.length - 3, str.length()))
```

Be careful with the indices in the substring method since the last parameter indicates the place of the first character not to be included in the substring.
Same result but with the `endsWith(String)` method:

```
if(str.length() >= 4 && str.endsWith(str.substring(0, 3)))
```

Or with only `sunbstring(int, int)` method:

```
if(str.length() >= 4 
&& str.substring(0, 3).equals(str.substring(str.length() - 3, str.length())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from

```
((str.startsWith(str.substring(0, 2))).equals(str.endsWith(str
                .substring(str.length() - 3, str.length() - 1))))
```

Which is basically coming down to `boolean.equals(...)`, which can't be done, as `boolean` is not an `Object`

You could, instead, make use of `String#startsWith` and `String#endsWith`, for example...

```
if (str.length() >= 4 &&
    str.endsWith(str.substring(0, 2)) &&
    str.startsWith(str.substring(str.length() - 2))) {
```

Or maybe even

```
if (str.length() >= 4 &&
    str.substring(0, 2).equals(str.substring(str.length() - 2))) {
```